# Matlab text on Linux with Intel graphics

Tags: linux, matlab, debian, drivers, backport

On my laptop with an Intel HD 5500 graphics card, if I run Matlab (locally or on a remote machine) some text in menus and inside figures is unreadable. This is what the Edit menu of an empty figure looks like:

[image: Edit menu of an empty figure window]

The lines that are unreadable seem randomly chosen but they're not: in every new figure, it's those menu items.

The solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070818) of starting matlab with the option `-softwareopengl` works -then the text is readable- when I start Matlab on my own machine. On remote Matlab sessions however it still produces unreadable text.

The suggestion of [using backports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207855) to get rid of the problem unfortunately does not work: even with the backported drivers the text is not right.

Do other linux drivers (perhaps outside of the Debian repositories) solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to open a support request with TMW directly for this issue.

Comment: I think this is more specific to my laptop's setup than to Matlab: (1) my colleagues with different computers don't have this problem, (2) there is a solution -the option provided by TMW- that fixes it on my local machine.

Comment: How do you run matlab remotely? Are you using x, vnc, something else?

Comment: The remote session is an X session over ssh (using `ssh -Y`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a file called 'java.opts' in the matlab binary directory (e.g. /path/to/matlab/R201Xy/bin/glnxa64) with contents

```
-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false
```

Comment: Must admit I haven't checked this. The problem disappeared with the latest version of Matlab.